# Exclude Similarities in List of Strings to extract the Difference

Tags: c#

I have a list of sentences that are the same except for the Title of the book.

How can I loop through the list and exclude the similarities to find the title of the book?

(This is an example, it can be any short sentence with similarities.)

> The book named Lord of the Flies is a classic.
>   The book named To Kill a Mockingbird is a classic.
>   The book named The Catcher in the Rye is a classic.

---

The problem I'm having is that I cannot simply use `regex` or `Contains()` to find the Title in the sentence, because I don't know what the next Sentence or Book Title will be. I'm searching through many from an external source, so I thought I could extract what's between the similar words.

`The book named` *The Catcher in the Rye* `is a classic`.

---

```
List<string> sentences = new List<string>() { };
List<string> titles = new List<string>() { };

sentences.Add("The book named Lord of the Flies is a classic.");
sentences.Add("The book named To Kill a Mockingbird is a classic.");
sentences.Add("The book named The Catcher in the Rye is a classic.");

foreach (String title in sentences)
{
    // what to do here?

    // add title to titles list
}
```

My idea is to compare all strings in the list with each other, exclude the similar parts of the strings, and you are left with the Title. But I don't know how to go about doing it.

Comment: On the contrary, this seems like the _perfect_ time to use Regex. Is [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UP7ngW) what you're looking for?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that in your source data you have many different prefixes and suffixes in the sentences that contain the book titles? It's not just `"The book named "` and `" is a classic."`?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, it can be many different prefixes and suffixes. But I always add similar matching strings to the list.

Comment: If your sentences list are always similar you can just use Substring to get the value, if not create a list of prefixes and suffixes, and then for each sentence loop through the prefixes and suffixes to find a match. When you find the match you can then use sentences[x].Substring() to parse out the title using the length of the matches.

Comment: If they are always the same you could also use .Replace and replace the prefix and suffix with an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an interesting problem, so I've played around with it a little and came up with the following (cumbersome) solution:

Find the first index where any of the sentences have a different char,
then do the same in the reversed sentences,
and then use `Substring` to extract only the different parts of the sentences:

```
List<string> ExtractDifferences(List<string> sentences)
{
    var firstDiffIndex = GetFirstDifferenceIndex(sentences);
    var lastDiffIndex = GetFirstDifferenceIndex(sentences.Select(s => new string(s.Reverse().ToArray())).ToList());
    return sentences.Select(s => s.Substring(firstDiffIndex, s.Length - lastDiffIndex - firstDiffIndex)).ToList();
}


int GetFirstDifferenceIndex(IList<string> strings)
{
    int firstDifferenceIndex = int.MaxValue;

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.Count; i++)
    {
        var current = strings[i];
        var prev = strings[i == 0 ? strings.Count - 1 : i - 1];

        var firstDiffIndex = current
            .Select((c, j) => new { CurrentChar = c, Index = j })
            .FirstOrDefault(ci => ci.CurrentChar != prev[ci.Index])
            .Index;

        if (firstDiffIndex < firstDifferenceIndex)
        {
            firstDifferenceIndex = firstDiffIndex;
        }
    }
    return firstDifferenceIndex;
}
```

I guess the `GetFirstDifferenceIndex` method can be written differently, perhaps better using linq, but I don't have enough time to play with it.

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/FXXSVN30342)

Comment: It is working well in my project. Do you know how it could be changed to still work if the suffix in the string is missing?

Comment: If none have suffixes [you don't need to change anything.](http://rextester.com/AEL39333). If only some of the sentences have suffixes then it's a harder problem.

Comment: It should work fine then. They should all be similar, so if one is missing suffix, all will.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help. I'll bet you know what to do next :-)

Comment: For efficiency sake I would change two things: 1) not reverse the string 2) loop would be faster than the linq query

Comment: @kevin don't worrie so much about performance. Write code for readability. Set performance goals and measure your code against them. If it's too slow, find the bottle necks and fix them.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - I'm always thinking about performance and readability. I do a lot of work parsing large text files, so performance is always important to me.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I found a bug, I posted a new question, maybe you can help. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49744331/6806643

Answer (score 0):

A working solution using LINQ:

```
List<string> sentences = new List<string>() { };
List<string> titles = new List<string>() { };

sentences.Add("The book named Lord of the Flies is a classic.");
sentences.Add("The book named To Kill a Mockingbird is a classic.");
sentences.Add("The book named The Catcher in the Rye is a classic.");
sentences.Add("Hello");
sentences.Add("The book named ");


titles = sentences.Where(sentence => sentence.Length > "The book named ".Length + " is a classic".Length)
            .GroupBy(sentence => sentence.Substring(0, 15), sentence => sentence.Remove(sentence.Length - " is a classic".Length).Substring("The book named ".Length))
            .Where(g => g.Key == "The book named ")
            .SelectMany(g => g)
            .ToList();

foreach (var title in titles)
    WriteLine(title);
```

First, it filters out sentences too short to meet the criteria, then groups the results by first 15 letters and extracts the titles with `String.Remove`.