# Extracting Title between Similar Prefix and Suffix Bug

Tags: c#

I found a bug in the previous answer to my question. I would like to see if anyone can help fix it.

**Question**
[Exclude Similarities in List of Strings to extract the Difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49714338/6806643)

**Answer**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49714706/6806643

---

I have a list of sentences that are the same except for the Title of the book.

The code loops through, finding similar `prefixes` and `suffixes`, and extracts the Title in-between.

> The book named Lord of the Flies is a classic.
> The book named To Kill a Mockingbird is a classic.
> The book named The Catcher in the Rye is a classic.

`The book named` (prefix) and `is a classic` (suffix) will be removed.

**Demo**
http://rextester.com/FXXSVN30342

---

### The Bug

http://rextester.com/DUJZN22339

If the string does not have a similar `suffix` and book titles all end the same character, that character ends up being removed. In this case `s`.

> The book named Lord of the Flies
> The book named Wuthering Heights
> The book named Great Expectations

Filtered

> Lord of the Flie
> Wuthering Height
> Great Expectation

---

### C Sharp

Note: This is an example list, I use it on different strings than book names.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sentences = new List<string>() 
    { 
        "The book named Lord of the Flies",
        "The book named Wuthering Heights",
        "The book named Great Expectations"
    };
    
    var titles = ExtractDifferences(sentences);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", titles));

}

static List<string> ExtractDifferences(List<string> sentences)
{
    var firstDiffIndex = GetFirstDifferenceIndex(sentences);
    var lastDiffIndex = GetFirstDifferenceIndex(sentences.Select(s => new string(s.Reverse().ToArray())).ToList());
    return sentences.Select(s => s.Substring(firstDiffIndex, s.Length - lastDiffIndex - firstDiffIndex)).ToList();
}


static int GetFirstDifferenceIndex(IList<string> strings)
{
    int firstDifferenceIndex = int.MaxValue;

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.Count; i++)
    {
        var current = strings[i];
        var prev = strings[i == 0 ? strings.Count - 1 : i - 1];

        var firstDiffIndex = current
            .Select((c, j) => new { CurrentChar = c, Index = j })
            .FirstOrDefault(ci => ci.CurrentChar != prev[ci.Index])
            .Index;

        if (firstDiffIndex < firstDifferenceIndex)
        {
            firstDifferenceIndex = firstDiffIndex;
        }
    }
    return firstDifferenceIndex;
}
```

Comment: Instead of comparing each character just split the strings into the words and compare those instead.

Comment: @juharr That sounds like it will work. If you can post any examples you can come up with.

Comment: @juharr What would happen if the string began with `The` and the Title began with `The`? They would both be removed?

Comment: Actually, even if you add a prefix, the code would still remove that last s from the book name. Frankly, I'm not sure how can this be altered without some more information about the sentences themselves - The code is looking for the last matching char as the last char of the prefix, and then do the same for the strings in reverse. Perhaps it's better to look for the last matching word, but that would require a more sophisticated code, including deciding where a word ends (might not always be a space - it can be a dot, comma, or many other punctuation elements).

Comment: @ZoharPeled I noticed another thing, it will remove even similar parts of the Titles. http://rextester.com/JCCP44237

Comment: Yes - the main problem here is how to identity where the prefix/suffix ends/starts and where the content boundaries are. The less sentences you have the more likely you are to get it wrong. In the last rextester link it would also be impossible to a human without prior knowledge of at least one of the books to figure that out.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I wonder if it could be done like this: 1. Split string by words. 2. Group longest occurrence of matching words. 3. Remove those occurrences from the string. Then it will not remove single characters within words.

Comment: I haven't had enough sleep so I might be over-complicating this in my head, but I think this is a harder problem then what I first thought of it. Currently, I think I better use whatever little brain power I have left to do my day job. I hope you can get the correct solution either yourself or with the help of another stackoverflow member by the time I'll be able to rethink this.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Alright thanks, I will continue to work on finding a solution.

Comment: Yes, if all the book titles start with the same word or words then you'd have the same issue, but you'd have that issue anyway with the character solution.  The difference is you won't lose part of a word that way.  I don't think you'll find a perfect solution that isn't very complicated anyway.

Comment: Actually while thinking about a solution that splits the sentences into words I realizes that it wouldn't be the most performant and really all you have to do is back track to the closes word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the issue of removing part of a word simply by back tracking to the closest word boundary.  Here I'm just assuming that's a space, but you might want to expand that if needed.

The first thing that jumps to my mind in handling book titles with common words is to assume they will be capitalized.  So you could also stop at the first character that is a capital except for the first letter of the sentence.

Additionally your current algorithm can be improved by not comparing the first to the last.  Just comparing the 1st and 2nd, then 2nd and 3rd, and so on up to the next to last and the last is good enough.  And if it ever determines that the start of the differences is at zero you can immediately return.

```
static int GetFirstDifferenceIndex(IList<string> strings)
{
    int firstDifferenceIndex = int.MaxValue;

    for (int i = 1; i < strings.Count; i++)
    {
        var current = strings[i];
        var prev = strings[i - 1];

        // Index of first character that is different or that is a capital letter
        // other than the first character of the sentence.
        var firstDiffIndex = current
            .Select((c, j) => new { CurrentChar = c, Index = j })
            .FirstOrDefault(ci => ci.CurrentChar != prev[ci.Index]
                            || (ci.Index != 0 && char.IsUpper(ci.CurrentChar)))
            .Index;

        // back track to the beginning or until the previous char is a space
        while(firstDiffIndex > 0 && current[firstDiffIndex-1] != ' ')
        {
            firstDiffIndex--;
        }

        if(firstDiffIndex == 0) return 0;

        if (firstDiffIndex < firstDifferenceIndex)
        {
            firstDifferenceIndex = firstDiffIndex;
        }
    }
    return firstDifferenceIndex;
}
```

That will take the sentences

> The book named Lord of the Rings
>
> The book named Lord of the Flies

and output

> Lord of the Rings
>
> Lord of the Flies

It will also work with book titles with common endings when you reverse the sentences because of the back tracking

> The book named The Old Man and The Sea is a classic
>
> The book named Alone on a Wide, Wide Sea is a classic

will result in

> The Old Man and The Sea
>
> Alone on a Wide, Wide Sea

But of course this relies on the book titles first and last words starting with a capital letter and only the first character of the prefix being a capital (and none of the suffixes starting with a capital).  To handle the cases that could fail you'd have to start analyzing the parts of speech which would result in a very complex algorithm.

Comment: The strings I'm using aren't always clean. They can contain dashes, parentheses, etc. Here's an example, see how it doesn't remove the matching suffix `(500 - Is A Test)`. I have to figure different combinations that might confuse it. http://rextester.com/MZLZ59398

Comment: @MattMcManis It fails on that because of the capitalization.  If it were `(500 - is a test)` it would work.  Like I said if there is capitalization outside of the title then that part will not help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:
Only if Prefix (The book named) and Suffix (is a classic.) are present - the Book Name will be part of output.
Ex:

- The book named Lord of the Flies is a classic.  --> Will Pass - Book
  Name: Lord of the Flies
- The book Lord of the Flies is a classic. --> Will NOT Pass
- The book named Lord of the Flies is classic. --> Will NOT Pass

If above is correct - Why not use Regex - that are built for Pattern matching purposes:

```
^(?<Prefix>The book named) (?<BookName>.+) (?<Suffix>is a classic.)$
```

This regex will find Book Names for you (Remember to use Ignore Case Regex Option). See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I'm importing the strings from an external source. I don't know what the sentence prefix or suffix will be, they are always different. I have the program figure it out by finding the similarities and extracting the difference.

Comment: The prefix could be `The book named` or it could be `The movie called` or anything.